# how to use Play 2.1.1 async requests and futures

Tags: asynchronous, playframework-2.0, future

The code below doesn't compile and I don't know how to fix it.

```
def doAsync(n: Int) = Action {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  Async {
    val f1 = Future.successful(n)

    f1.map(x => x match {
      case 10 => Ok("first")
      case _ => {
        val f2 = Future.successful(n)
        f2.map(y => Ok("second"))
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The line `f2.map(y => Ok("second"))` produces the **compile error**:

> type mismatch; found:
>   scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult[String]] required:
>   play.api.mvc.Result

The core `"business logic" is: f2` only must run `if n is not 10`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

f1 is going to be a future of a result.

You're returning a result for case 10, and a a future of a result otherwise. You need to put the result into the same terms. Try:

```
f1 flatMap {x => x match {
  case 10 => Future.successful(Ok("first"))
  case _ => {
    val f2 = Future.successful(n)
    f2.map(y => Ok("second"))
  }
}
```